# Interacting with appindicator icon and menus from LDTP

Tags: 12.04, application-development, indicator, testing

I'm using [LDTP](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/) Python API in order to test desktop applications under Ubuntu (Unity shell, Ubuntu 12.04). I can't find if there's any available way to interact with `appindicator` icon and menus using the API, and if it's possible at all. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, desktop applications are wonderfully tested with autopilot. It was originally written to test unity, unity indicators, and etc.

**What is autopilot?**

*Autopilot is a functional testing tool. It simulates user actions by generating keyboard and mouse events, and then testing the internal state of the application in question. It works for gtk and qt based applications.
Autopilot is written in python. Tests are standard python unit tests and introspection is done using DBus calls.*

Check out the official documentation:
http://unity.ubuntu.com/autopilot/

Here's a tutorial as well to get you started:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/cookbook/mobile/how-to-write-autopilot-tests/

There's even a video by yours truly showing how it can be used to work on qml/qt applications:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qD_e_xqlBbg